# How to find a document using a value to search in a range?

Tags: search, range, couchdb, couchdb-2.x

The database is the range of geolocation of IP address and each document look like this;

```
{
  "_id": "1000013824",
  "_rev": "1-b747bd47d44efe619c9b4f8d867131ad",
  "f": "1000079359",
  "p": "CN"
}
```

I created a view to make the output like this:

```
"total_rows":202238,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"0","key":["0","16777215"],"value":"ZZ"},
{"id":"1000013824","key":["1000013824","1000079359"],"value":"CN"},
{"id":"1000079360","key":["1000079360","1000083455"],"value":"JP"},
{"id":"1000083456","key":["1000083456","1000084479"],"value":"JP"},
```

But I am unable to search a value, for example, 1000013825 which is the first document but the value does not correspond to a startkey or endkey. How can I do this?
Using JS and the data in a array, I could do this:

```
        return array.find(doc=> {
                if (doc._id <= this && doc.f >= this) {
                    return doc.p;
                }
            };
```

But I do not have a clue how to do it in CouchDB 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the CouchDB Core API, you could query the dodument from the database (not the view) by the use of [`POST /{db}/_find`](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html) and the following request body:

```
{
    "selector": {
        "f": {"$gte": value }
    },
    "fields": ["f", "p"],
    "sort":[ 
        {"f": "asc"}
    ],
    "limit": 1
}
```

> Please note that an index must previously be created for the sort field `f` (see [/db/_index](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#db-index)).

Comment: Just to update the link for the /db/_index: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.3.1/api/database/find.html#db-index

Comment: I am making: curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/fneon_paisip -d '{"selector":{"f":{"$gte":"1045150219"}},"fields": ["p"],"sort":[{"f": "asc"}],"limit": 1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
but it does not return the fields defined in "fields"; only id and rev fields. Also, everytime i make the find, it returns a different id as result. It is not working.
Also the ID that returns is completly different from the ones in the database.

Comment: I was missing the _find after the name of database: curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/fneon_paisip/_find -d '{"selector":{"f":{"$gte":"1045150219"}},"fields": ["p"],"sort":[{"f": "asc"}],"limit": 1}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
Now it works. Thank you.